Error , list reloads after, open or close v-navigation-drawer on vuetify, causes slowness
Sumary
Using vuetify, v-navigation-drawer or v-main,
I identified a severe slowdown in my application when there were many images on the page, and trying to scroll, or open the navigation-drawer, it would hang.
So I inserted logs into the loop and found that the list was reloading when open the panel.
It seems unnoticeable on the list.
but, it caused crashes and slowness, when load many images.
I create, in vuetify play , more simple version to demonstrate.
Example LINK
Click here to open a Example In Vuetify Play
Details:
The example should contain a data list a v-for, which will display a lot of data, preferably images, basically a v-for, and a v-navigation-drawer panel
1 Click on button 1 ADD RECORDS TO THE LIST +30 onClick to add, more records, to test.
2 open your console to view logs .
I inserted a command to insert logs inside v-for.
This way I discovered the reason for the slowness.
3 CLEAR THE CONSOLE
use the button, if you see log records in the console, to observe when you will add new logs, when opening the panel
4 - Toggle v-navigation-drawer visible, and observe logs
5 - Conclusion Description Error, cause slowless
Apparently the list is re-rendered after opening the v-navigation-drawer panel. Clean the console. observe the console. when opening v-navigation-drawer, it will add the log records again. with each click + 30 records will be added. It depends on the machine to observe the slowness. In mine, I see slowness with 1000 records. When panel open, the log was added , the list refresh, it is not perceptible, but causes slowess, when opening the panel, and the scrolling lists. Its not perceptible, with simple records, but, cause, very sloly, For me, Its cause very slowly when using more lot records, or 200 images. if you add more records you can see the slowdown happening.
6 This code example:
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-card>
        <v-container>
          <v-row>
            <v-col><h1>Error on v-navigation-drawer test.</h1></v-col>
          </v-row>
          <v-row>
            <v-col><h2>Description:</h2></v-col>
          </v-row>
          <v-row>
            <v-col
              ><p>
                Apparently the list is re-rendered after opening the
                v-navigation-drawer panel
              </p></v-col
            >
          </v-row>
          <v-row>
            <v-col>
              <v-btn color="primary" @click="loadList()" variant="outlined">
                1 ADD RECORDS TO THE LIST +30 onClick
              </v-btn>
            </v-col>
            <v-col>
              <p>
                Total de Registros:
                <strong> {{list_products.length}} </strong>
              </p></v-col
            >
          </v-row>
          <v-row></v-row>
          <v-row>
            <v-col
              ><h3>2 open your console to view logs .</h3>
              <p>
                I inserted a command to insert logs inside v-for. This way I
                discovered the reason for the slowness.
              </p></v-col
            >
          </v-row>
          <v-row>
            <v-col></v-col>
          </v-row>
          <v-row>
            <v-col
              ><v-btn
                color="primary"
                @click="clearConsole()"
                variant="outlined"
              >
                3 CLEAR THE CONSOLE
              </v-btn>
            </v-col>
            <v-col
              ><v-switch
                v-model="autoClear"
                label="Auto Clear After Load"
              ></v-switch
            ></v-col>
          </v-row>
          <v-row>
            <v-col
              ><p>
                use the button, if you see log records in the console, to
                observe when you will add new logs, when opening the panel
              </p></v-col
            >
          </v-row>
          <v-row>
            <v-col>
              <v-btn
                color="primary"
                @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"
                variant="outlined"
              >
                4 - Toggle v-navigation-drawer visible, and observe logs
              </v-btn></v-col
            >
            <v-col
              ><v-switch v-model="drawer" label="PANEL IS VISIBLE"></v-switch
            ></v-col>
          </v-row>
          <v-row>
            <v-col><h2>Conclusion Description Error:</h2></v-col>
          </v-row>
          <v-row>
            <v-col
              ><p>
                Apparently the list is re-rendered after opening the
                v-navigation-drawer panel
              </p></v-col
            >
          </v-row>
          <v-row>
            <v-col>
              <p>
                Clean the console. observe the console. when opening
                v-navigation-drawer, it will add the log records again.
              </p>
              <p>
                with each click + 30 records will be added. It depends on the
                machine to observe the slowness. In mine, I see slowness with
                1000 records.
              </p>
              <p>
                the log was added , the list refresh, it is not perceptible, but
                causes slowess, when opening the panel, and the scrolling lists.
                <br />
                For me, Its cause very slowly when using 300 images.
                <br />
                Its not perceptible, with simple records, but, cause, very
                sloly, when loading, 300 images,
              </p>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
          <v-row
            ><v-col><h2>Table Data</h2></v-col></v-row
          >
          <v-row>
            <v-col>
              <table class=".table-bordered">
                <tbody v-for="prod in list_products" :key="prod.id">
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      {{prod.title}}
                      {{logDebug("itemreconsultadonalista",prod)}}
                    </td>
                    <td>{{prod.rating}}</td>
                    <td>{{prod.shippingInformation}}</td>
                    <td>{{prod.reviewerName}}</td>
                    <td>{{prod.reviewerEmail}}</td>
                    <td>{{prod.availabilityStatus}}</td>
                    <td>{{prod.availabilityStatus}}</td>
                    <td>{{prod.price}}</td>
                    <td>{{prod.tags}}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="9">{{prod.description}}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="9">
                      <table>
                        <tbody v-for="img in prod.images">
                          <tr>
                            <td><img :src="img" />{{img}}</td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
      </v-card>
    </v-main>
    <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" temporary location="right">
      <v-card>
        <v-container>
          <v-btn
            color="primary"
            @click="clearConsole()"
            variant="outlined"
            block
          >
            2 CLEAR THE CONSOLE
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn
            block
            color="primary"
            @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"
            variant="outlined"
          >
            CLOSE
          </v-btn>
        </v-container>
      </v-card>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      autoClear: true,
      title: 'Error on v-navigation-drawer test.',
      teste_nav: { open: false },
      list_images: [],
      list_products: [],
      drawer: false,
      warns: {
        list: true,
      },

      fake: undefined,
      newName: undefined,
      newNumber: undefined,
      people: [{ name: 'Alpha', number: 1 }],
      headers: [
        { text: 'Name', value: 'name' },
        { text: 'Number', value: 'number' },
        { text: 'Inputs', value: 'name' },
      ],
    }),

    methods: {
      logDebug(pstr, item) {
        console.warn(pstr, item.title)
      },
      clearConsole() {
        console.clear()
      },
      loadList(pstr) {
        console.log('loadList')
        const self = this

        this.warns.list = false

        /* providing access token in bearer */
        fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products', {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        })
          .then(r => r.json())
          .then(json => {
            console.log('json', json)

            for (var i = 0; i < json.products.length; i++) {
              var item = json.products[i]
              self.list_products.push(item)
            }
            window.setTimeout(function () {
              console.clear()
            }, 100)
          })
      },
    },
    
  }
</script>

7 Can anyone tell me what I did wrong??
Thanks!

The output means that Vue re-evaluates the statement {{logDebug("itemreconsultadonalista",prod)}}, which is necessary because it is not a reactive value. It does not mean that the elements are re-rendered. When playing around with your example, the only slowdown I can make out is that the drawer opens only after the button animation has finished, and the animation is noticeably slowed down (with a regular button, there is no slowdown). Is that what you mean? One way or another, I think the way to address this is to avoid endless lists by using pagination.

This depends on the structure created, which is more complex, for example, there are more elements within the loop.
In my app, I have many different elements on the screen, and the list is not so simple, it creates a card with an image and several buttons. I noticed it was slow when opening the panel, with only 100 records.
That's when I added this log, to try to identify it.
was placed just to demonstrate, that it is passing through there, that is what causes slowness.That's why in the example I put the button, + 30 records, you can remove the logs, and check that the slowdown will start

I am not seeing any slowdown with your example, even with +2000 entries, both Firefox and Chrome.Does virtual scroll improve the situation?

As I said, this example is just to demonstrate. Depending on your machine, you may feel a slight delay when opening and closing, using +4000
This problem gets worse when we have more complex structures in v-for, with buttons, cards, etc.

If your problem is complexity, you have to manage that yourself (i.e. pagination, virtual scroll). Why do you need thousands of entries on the same page?

I'm not developing this page, it's just an example for you to see that I created to demonstrate. I can't copy my app's huge code here.

I am developing a complex APP.
I've made other apps with Vue (without Vuetify) and custom panels, and I've never had this problem. But with vuetify, it refreshes unnecessarily when opening the panel. Is this the expected behavior?
I am creating a large robust web app system. It's not a simple page. The slowdown that occurs is freezing, lasting half a second, with a second for the list of 200 records, as it is refreshing and should not when opening a panel or displaying the toolbar.
What it's telling me is that vuetify cannot be used for these cases.

Hard to say when your example does not reproduce the behavior at all (200 records with 1s vs +4000 records with a "slight delay"). If you find a way to reproduce it, let me know.

Like I said. The list refreshes when the panel opens. Proof of this is access to the log. This behavior for me is WRONG this is what causes chrome to freeze. And this behavior for me is wrong! If you think the behavior is correct, that's your opinion.
I'm looking for someone here who knows how to SOLVE this! I don't want the list to refresh when opening the panel.
Or I can't use it in my complex APP, vuetify is only used for simple pages.

Have a look at v-memo, see if that helps. Good luck with your APP. Bye.
